# How to get the list of all rooms in openfire server

Tags: javascript, xmpp, cross-platform, ngcordova, strophe

Can someone please guide me on how to retrieve the list of all available rooms in openfire using strophe.js. I did not find anything really usefull related to this topic.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent few hours to find a solution, but it was easier than expected. I will add this part of code, so may be someone will need it in a future.

```
        getListRooms = function(server){
        var iq;
        iq = $iq({
          to: server,
          from: connection.jid,
          type: "get"
        }).c("query", {
          xmlns: Strophe.NS.DISCO_ITEMS
        });
      connection.sendIQ(iq.tree(), function (iq) {
        console.log(iq);
        if (!iq || iq.length == 0)
            return;
        //jquery load data after loading the page.This function updates data after jQuery loading
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {

            $(iq).find("item").each(function () {
//your function to update
 });
        });
        console.log('success, all rooms received'); }, function (err) { console.log('error, something went wrong with rooms receivig', err); });
    }
```

Comment: what i server in this